# GL_POLYGON is not drawing a closed polygon for 3 points

Tags: opengl, polygon

I am drawing in line mode using `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)`.
When I draw a polygon using `glBegin(GL_POLYGON)` I get the following result, see the blue lines:

[image: polygon is not closed]

but when I draw it using `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)` I get the following result, see the blue lines:

[image: a closed polygon/triangle]

I am on Windows 10, on a VMware virtual machine. OpenGL details using glcapsviewer:

```
OpenGL version: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0 (git-1d8818d)
Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
```

What can the issue in using `GL_POLYGON` mode that I am not getting a closed triangle?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: the problem is very environment and OpenGL implementation specific, both examples works perfectly on other OpenGL implementations, I'll see if I can get a working example that can produce the above issue in the above environment. I'll appreciate if I can get some clues, hints on what can cause such inconsistency. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your polygons don't look convex. OpenGL does allow drawing convex polygons only. If you try otherwise the results are undefined.

Comment: if the direction of angle does not matter (i.e. clockwise or anti-clockwise), a triangle is always a convex polygon,

Comment: @mkashif: That's right, but if you look at the shapes you have in your first picture, this doesn't look like a "pure" triangle to me. To me it looks like as if you have extranous vertices in there, that mess up your drawing. That being said, GL_POLYGON has been deprecated anyway.

Comment: thanks for reply, both above pictures are created with same coordinates, in one the polygon is closed in other one of the line is drawn arbitrarily (in all three triangles)